# Intercepting template content with ActionView

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have a Haml template with a bunch of “custom tags” scattered around, e.g. `{{REPLACE_ME}}`. Before rendering this template, I am going through the template and replacing all occurrences using Ruby’s `String#gsub`.

That has not been a problem—I have simply created a custom template handler, which essentially acts as a middleman by first modifying the template source and then passing it on to the Haml template handler.

For each occurrence of one of these “custom tags” in the view, it adds to a numerator that is stored in the background. The problem that I am facing, however, is that the numerator is being bumped up for content that will never be displayed to the user, e.g. `<% if false %>{{SECTION_NO}}<% end %>`.

Such content as above should be filtered out before I replace the content. I seem, however, to have hit a wall, as the Haml (and ERB) handlers return a content buffer and not the “end/finished” content.

Is there a straight-forward solution to this issue?

Here is an example of a view:

```
- if true
  %h1 {{SECTION_NO}}

- if false
  %h1 {{SECTION_NO}}

- if true
  %h1 {{SECTION_NO}}
```

So basically, I need a way to filter out the middle (false-statement) of the view source before replacing and numerating occurrences of “{{SECTION_NO}}”.

For reference, here is the gist of the template handler I created for this purpose:

```
class ActionView::Template::Handlers::Caml
  def initialize
    @section = 0
    @paragraph = 0
    @references = {}
  end

  def call(template)
    rendered_haml = ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:haml).call(template)

    updated_source = render_sections(rendered_haml)
    updated_source = render_paragraphs(updated_source)
    updated_source = render_references(updated_source)

    return ActionView::Template.new(
      updated_source,
      template.identifier,
      template.handler,
      {
        locals: template.locals,
        virtual_path: template.virtual_path,
        updated_at: template.updated_at
      }
    )
  end

  private

  def render_sections(source)
    source.gsub(/{{section:([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)}}/).each do |match|
      fail 'Key already exists.' if @references.key?($1)
      @section += 1
      @references[$1] = "#{@section}"
      "#{@section}"
    end
  end

  def render_paragraphs(source)
    # ...
  end

  def render_references(source)
    source.gsub(/{{([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)}}/).each do |match|
      @references.fetch($1)
    end
  end
end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(
  :caml,
  ActionView::Template::Handlers::Caml.new
)
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why wouldn't use just use `#{whatever}` to drop data into your templates?

Comment: In the templates, I can both define (`{{section:first}}`) and refer (`{{first}}`) to sections, i.e. get their IDs. The reason that would not work is that in a lot of cases, I refer to the section before it has been defined, which means I must parse the view by first going through all definitions and numerating them, and then thereafter going through all references and replacing them with the appropriate numerations/IDs.

Comment: @meagar? Do you have any suggestions?